# ggplot dismisses x axis factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following issue: if I run the code, my labels for the X axis loose for some unknown reason the assigned factor levels and instead of order: 1 week, 2 week it becomes: 1 week, 10 week... when I use `geom_line` AND `geom_point`:

```
datax <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justasmundeikis/stackoverflow/main/example.csv")
df <- datax %>%
        select(2,4,5,7,8,10,11,14,15)%>%
        rename(week_nr=savaites_mirusiuju_label.en,
               county_c=apskritysLR,
               county=apskritysLR_label.en,
               age_group_c=amzius_mirusiuju,
               age_group=amzius_mirusiuju_label.en,
               sex_c=Lytis,
               sex=Lytis_label.en,
               year=LAIKOTARPIS,
               values=obsValue)%>%
        filter(age_group!="Not indicated")%>%
        mutate(week_nr=factor(week_nr,
                        levels=paste(1:53, "week")))


x <- df %>%
        filter(age_group=="25–29",
               sex_c==0,
               county_c=="00")%>%
        group_by(year, week_nr)%>%
        summarise(values=sum(values))%>%
        mutate(cat=as.factor(ifelse(year>=2020,1,0)))

ggplot(x,aes(x=week_nr, values, group=year))+
        geom_line(data = x%>%filter(cat==1), col="red")+
        geom_point(data = x%>%filter(cat==0), col="grey")+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

... but if I run the last chunk without `geom_line`

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=week_nr, values, group=year))+
        #geom_line(data = x%>%filter(cat==1), col="red")+
        geom_point(data = x%>%filter(cat==0), col="grey")+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

then the axis label order is correct.
My main goal is to have grey point for all years, but 2020. For 2020 I want to have a red line, therefore i create the `cat` factor variable.

How could I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is made more difficult by your weeks being factors rather than numbers from 1 to 53 (you could always make the x axis numeric and *label* it with text which would fix the problem). Anyway, the reason this reordering is happening is because not all the factor levels of `week_nr` appear in the subset `cat == "1"`. The unused factor levels are dropped, which triggers a re-ordering. There are a couple ways to fix this:

1. Add `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`
2. Move the `geom_point` call before the `geom_line` call, since the dataset used for the first geom drawn determines the levels that are used.

```r
ggplot(x, aes(week_nr, values, group = year)) +
  geom_line(data = x %>% filter(cat == "1"), color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = x %>% filter(cat == "0"), color = "grey") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what exactly is the issue and what happens under the hood ... but you can solve your issue by plotting the `geom_point` first and the `geom_line` second. I can only guess that the reason is that not all levels of your factor `week_nr` are present in both datasets ...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

datax <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justasmundeikis/stackoverflow/main/example.csv")
df <- datax %>%
  select(2,4,5,7,8,10,11,14,15)%>%
  rename(week_nr=savaites_mirusiuju_label.en,
         county_c=apskritysLR,
         county=apskritysLR_label.en,
         age_group_c=amzius_mirusiuju,
         age_group=amzius_mirusiuju_label.en,
         sex_c=Lytis,
         sex=Lytis_label.en,
         year=LAIKOTARPIS,
         values=obsValue)%>%
  filter(age_group!="Not indicated") %>% 
  mutate(week_nr=factor(week_nr,
                         levels=paste(1:53, "week")))

x <- df %>%
  filter(age_group=="25–29",
         sex_c==0,
         county_c=="00")%>%
  group_by(year, week_nr)%>%
  summarise(values=sum(values))%>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cat=ifelse(year>=2020,1,0))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'year' (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(x,aes(x=week_nr, values, group=year))+
  geom_point(data = x%>%filter(cat==0), col="grey")+
  geom_line(data = x%>%filter(cat==1), col="red")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Comment: Yes @stefan, you are on the right track. When `geom_line` is called, the data it is called with does not have weeks 52 or 53 in it. These levels are dropped, which triggers a re-ordering. So you can do as you have done and switch the `geom_line` and `geom_point` orders (so all levels are present in the first geom layer), or (perhaps more "properly"), add a `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to the plot, which prevents the forced re-ordering. If you are like me though, you would have been a bit surprised at this behaviour.

Comment: Hej @AllanCameron. Thanks for clarifying. As I already knew you are a real ggplot2 wizard and always a source of enlightenment. (: Happy Christmas. S.